# ArcGIS for Desktop 10.3 vs ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, arcgis-pro

I'm trying to upgrade to the 10.3 version of ArgGIS (currently, I have Advanced Desktop 10.2). When I go to the download page in my ESRI account, I'm given the option to download ArcGIS for Desktop or ArcGIS Pro

[image]

Which one should I download? What's the difference between these two?

I use ArcGIS Advanced Desktop 10.2 to do the following:

- network analysis using the Network Analyst tool
- spatial statistics using Spatial Analyst
- Lots of tasks processing raster data
- Extensive python scripting using the arcpy module in python 2.7

Basically I want the one that is the fastest and can do the most while also allowing me to do all the things I currently do in 10.2

Comment: I think you should read some of the comparative information out there http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis-pro/common-questions https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LiT39di2TR4

Comment: In truth, you're offered the option to download both, not just one *or* the other.

Comment: A word of caution is that there is a marked change in licensing conditions for ArcGIS Pro from those to which ArcGIS for Desktop users are accustomed.  It is worth reviewing [ArcGIS Pro License : Subscription license - will expire when maintenance stops](https://geonet.esri.com/thread/130120) and voting at [Are you in favour of ArcGIS Pro as Temporary use, subscription license that expires when maintenance stops?](https://geonet.esri.com/polls/1732), if you have not already.

Answer (score 4):

You should choose "ArcGIS for Desktop."  This should give you the latest version (10.3) of the software you are currently using.

ArcGIS Pro is a new, separate program that was released by ESRI in January 2015.  You can read more about it [here at ESRI's website](http://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/).  They have made it available to people who already have ArcMap licenses.

Answer (score 1):

10.3 is a "point" update to what you're currently using, 10.2. ArcGIS Pro is a new desktop product currently at version 1.0.